# WebMap that automatically links to Google Drive Spreadsheet

Tags: arcgis-online

I would like to create a webmap from a contacts spreadsheet stored in Google Drive that will update the map automatically when new data is added to the spreadsheet. I know I can do this with an ArcGIS Online Organisation subscription, but are there any other ways?

Answer (score 2):

CartoDB will do this easily, I believe.

There's also the google spreadsheet mapper:

http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/spreadsheet3.html

Answer (score 2):

A few other options I've discovered for Leaflet.js:

- Mapsheet ([on Github](https://github.com/jsoma/mapsheet))
- Tabletop.js ([demo here](http://csessig.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/creating-responsive-maps-with-leaflet-google-docs/))

Answer (score 0):

Fusion Tables is what you need. Create it in Google Drive. Works like spreadsheet that you can edit.